# virtualenv with gunicorn no working

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I am developing a django project which I'm doing in digitalocean servers in the instantiate (droplet) in which is created (by selecting an item) ubuntu server 14.04 + django.

far so good, but when configuring the instance with virtualenv
as the documentation says
http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deploy.html#using-virtualenv
the virtualenv is not recognized because when installing an app (with pip installer) eg "django framework rest" this is not recognized and throws 500 error since there is no such app.

I was also seeing this post
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/usinv-virtualenv-in-django-image
in which mention the modification of the configuration file in which you must assign the address of the new gunicorn that is created in the virtualenv but at the time of the service restart it throws an error 502: /

```
/* structure directory*/
/home/django
            /myproject (django)
            /envs/myapp (virtualenvs)


/* Gunicorn file */
description "Gunicorn daemon for Django project"

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on runlevel [!12345]

respawn

setuid django
setgid django
chdir /home/django

exec gunicorn \ (**Here is where you change the url and gave 502 error)
   --name=myproject \
   --pythonpath=myproject \
   --bind=0.0.0.0:9000 \
   --config /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn.py \
   conf.wsgi:application
```

have no idea why this situation? someone been in a situation like that can help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean about URLs, virtualenv has nothing to do with the URL. The answer you link to gives you the solution: you need to explicitly start the gunicorn that is installed inside the virtualenv, with `exec /path/to/my/virtualenv/bin/gunicorn ...`.

Comment: when I set the gunicorn, I entered the following routes:

    1- /home/django/envs/myproject/bin/gunicorn
    2- envs/myproject/bin/gunicorn
    3- /envs/myproject/bin/gunicorn

after I restart the gunicorn but still got the error 502

only the exec changed? or more

I'm modifying the file is: /etc/init/gunicorn.conf

Comment: 502 is a proxy error. Is nginx proxying to :9000? What do the nginx and gunicorn error logs show?

Comment: access xxx.xxx.xxx.101 - - [03/Dec/2014:09:39:58 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 583 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36"

Comment: error 2014/12/03 09:39:58 [error] 17216#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.101, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/", host: "myproject.com"

Comment: myproject.com host is only reference

Comment: (myproject)root@myproject:/home/django/myproject# which gunicorn
/home/django/envs/myproject/bin/gunicorn

Comment: root@clubnutricion:/home/django/myproject# which gunicorn
/usr/bin/gunicorn (without virtualenvs)

Comment: I understand gunicorn should take my virtualenvs in which I have installed different app to help me in my django project